# store response from $.get in a variable to use later

Tags: jquery, variables, get, store

I'm retrieving a response from a php with $.get, but how do I store the response in a variable so I can use it later in my code? Thanks!

```
   $.get('promo_getstate.php', {
            email: emailaddress,
            country: 'DE',
            lang: lang,
            source: '1304_Spring_dly'
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log('data is' + data);
                    getstate = data;
                 });
```

Comment: Use it in the callback

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're already doing that with the getstate assignment. Is it not working?

Comment: not working, how do I use it in a callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just declare the variable you want to set outside of the .get call itself. then it will be accessible inside of the callback function where you want to set it to the returned data.

```
var getstate = "";
$.get('promo_getstate.php', {
        email: emailaddress,
        country: 'DE',
        lang: lang,
        source: '1304_Spring_dly'
            }, function (data) {
                console.log('data is' + data);
                getstate = data;
             });
```

Comment: when you say that doesn't work... what does that mean? what does your console say, are there errors? does the request actually fire? all i did was copy your get method call and declare the variable outside the scope. That answers your question, but if theres is something not working then it is probably because you are using .get incorrectly

Comment: sorry, but the when I console.log the variable getstate it's value appears as nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the assignment can be accessed outside of the scope of the originating call.

If `getstate` isn't declared outside of the get request, then it won't be available for later calls.

The question is:  when or under what scope do you need this data?

Simply, you can just put it under the window's scope.  Although it's bad practice to put everything under the global scope, this will give you an idea of where to put it.

```
console.log('data is' + data);
window.getstate = data;
```

Now, anytime after it's assigned, it'll be available through either `window.getstate` or just `getstate`.

Answer (score 0):

The way $.get works is the browser is still getting data while it also processes lines after $.get .

```
$document.ready(function() {
    var $HTML="";  //global variable
     $(".button").click(function(event){
         console.log('before $.get: ');
         $.get('form1.html #form1', function(data){
             $HTML = data;
             console.log('inside $.get: ' + $HTML);
         });
      console.log('outside $.get: ' + $HTML);
});
```

So the solution is, all the code that needs the $.get value should go inside the get statement.
Or, you can somehow have it wait until the result has returned and the $.get code is complete before processing the lines after

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use

```js
setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('outside $.get: ' + $HTML);
}, 100);
```